# DBContext - Grid issue Many to Many relationship

Tags: c#, vb.net, entity-framework, dbcontext

What I am trying to do is setup a User-Role-Permission table structure using entity framework.  It seems that the tables are being created correctly but when I try to display the roles in a grid(devexpress) the data repeats itself:

So the first line in the grid shows the role.  If you then expand the role then all the Permissions will show under that role... then if you expand the permissions the role again will display under the permissions... then if you expand the role the permissions will show again... and so on.

Role1

--Permission1

--Permission2

----Role1

------Permission1

------Permission2

-----------Role1

etc...

```
Public Class User
    Inherits BaseTable

    <Required> _
    <StringLength(20)> _
    Public Property UserName As String = String.Empty
    <StringLength(50)> _
    Public Property FirstName As String = String.Empty
    <StringLength(50)> _
    Public Property LastName As String = String.Empty
    <StringLength(20)> _
    Public Property Password As String = String.Empty
    <StringLength(100)> _
    Public Property Email As String = String.Empty
    Public Property isActive As Boolean = False

    Public Overridable Property Roles As List(Of BO.Table.Role)
End Class

Public Class Role
    Inherits BaseTable

    <StringLength(50)> _
    Public Property RoleName As String = String.Empty
    <StringLength(500)> _
    Public Property RoleDescription As String = String.Empty

    Public Overridable Property Permissions As List(Of Permission)
End Class

Public Class Permission
    Inherits BaseTable

    <Required> _
    <StringLength(50)> _
    Public Property PermName As String = String.Empty

    Public Overridable Property Roles As List(Of BO.Table.Role)
End Class

Public Class BaseTable
    <Key> _
    <Column(Order:=1)> _
    Public Property ID As Integer = 0
End Class




Public Class UserContext
    Inherits DbContext
    Property Users As DbSet(Of BO.Table.User)
    Property Roles As DbSet(Of BO.Table.Role)
    Property Permissions As DbSet(Of BO.Table.Permission)

    Public Sub New()
        Entity.Database.SetInitializer(Of UserContext)(New UserInitializer)
    End Sub



    Protected Overrides Sub OnModelCreating(modelBuilder As DbModelBuilder)

        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove(Of PluralizingTableNameConvention)()

        modelBuilder.Entity(Of BO.Table.User)(). _
            Property(Function(p) p.UserName).
            HasColumnAnnotation("Index", New IndexAnnotation(New IndexAttribute With {.IsUnique = True}))
        modelBuilder.Entity(Of BO.Table.Permission)(). _
            Property(Function(p) p.PermName).
            HasColumnAnnotation("Index", New IndexAnnotation(New IndexAttribute With {.IsUnique = True}))
        modelBuilder.Entity(Of BO.Table.Role)(). _
            Property(Function(p) p.RoleName).
            HasColumnAnnotation("Index", New IndexAnnotation(New IndexAttribute With {.IsUnique = True}))

        modelBuilder.Entity(Of BO.Table.User)().HasMany(Function(p) p.Roles).WithMany().
        Map(Sub(m)
                m.ToTable("UserRole")
                m.MapLeftKey("UserID")
                m.MapRightKey("RoleID")
            End Sub)

        modelBuilder.Entity(Of BO.Table.Role)().HasMany(Function(p) p.Permissions).WithMany(Function(pp) pp.Roles).
        Map(Sub(m)
                m.ToTable("RolePermission")
                m.MapLeftKey("RoleID")
                m.MapRightKey("PermissionID")
            End Sub)

        MyBase.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder)
    End Sub
End Class


Public Class User
    Private _db As UserContext
    Public Sub New()
        _db = New UserContext
    End Sub

    Public Function GetRoles() As List(Of BO.Table.Role)
        Try
            Return _db.Roles.ToList
        Catch ex As Exception
            Logger.log(String.Format("DAL.Role.GetRoles|{0}", ex.ToString))
            Throw ex
        End Try
    End Function

End Class
```

I have an idea why it is displaying or grabbing the data like this but not totally sure how to fix it using entity framework.

In the end my tables are:

1. User is assigned role(s)
2. Role is assigned permission(s)
   etc...

User - Roles - UserRoles - Permission - RolePermission

Hope this explains it.

Comment: Don't inherit from the `dbContext`. To add more functionality use a `Partial Class`. Don't think that will fix your problem, but its a better approach to start with.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix my problem by removing the following line from the Permission Class:

```
Public Overridable Property Roles As List(Of BO.Table.Role)
```

Then in my User context I adjusted the relationship for the RolePermission as follows:

```
modelBuilder.Entity(Of BO.Table.Role)().HasMany(Function(p) p.Permissions).WithMany().
        Map(Sub(m)
                m.ToTable("RolePermission")
                m.MapLeftKey("RoleID")
                m.MapRightKey("PermissionID")
            End Sub)
```

After making those two changes the grid appears to work now.